# How to drag and drop rows from jqgrid using only a single column?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to re-order the jqgrid rows using only one specific column. Currently, the rows can be re-ordered by any column. I have it setup like below:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('sortableRows', {
            update: function (ev, ui) {
                SaveRowSorting();
            }
        });
```

But the above code allows the rows to be re-ordered by all columns, however we want to restrict it to only one column.

E.g, if we have 3 columns in a row. Then, we want the row to be re-ordered by only column1 and it shouldn't allow row sorting using the other two columns.

How could we achieve this? Any idea?

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Thanks,
Yash

Comment: What do you mean under "we want the row to be re-ordered by only column1"? Do you want that the contain of other column will stay unchanged after the re-ordering the rows? In the case you will do have a mix from the data of different rows. When can this have a sense? Probably you mean some other behavior?

Comment: Here are more details: Currently, we have row re-ordering enabled using jQuery("#list").jqGrid('sortableRows'). So, currently we are allowing the user to move rows up & down, then we save this this order of the rows in our database. However, users are able to move the rows up & down by holding(and dragging) any cell in a row. What we want to achieve is to restrict the user to move the rows up & down by just one cell in that row. Is it a little clear now? Please do let me know if it's not clear, then i could provide more detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sortable` property of colModel
Which is by-default true, ,you can set it to false while defining colModel.

Please visit http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

sortable property of all these columns is already set to false in the colModel.

Comment: It is better if you use "add comment" to comment an answer of somebody. Many questions will be more clear if you would add the code of the jqGrid in the body of your question. By the way you can modify the text of your question any time.

Comment: Hi Oleg, i posted this question from another PC, but i am on a different PC now. And i am not registered so i can't add comment to my question. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Here are more details:  Currently, we have row re-ordering enabled using jQuery("#list").jqGrid('sortableRows'). So, currently we are allowing the user to move rows up & down, then we save this this order of the rows in our database. However, users are able to move the rows up & down by holding(and dragging) any cell in a row. What we want to achieve is to restrict the user to move the rows up & down by just one cell in that row. Is it a little clear now? 

Please do let me know if it's not clear, then i could provide more detailed info.